# Unreachable Code after enum return

Tags: c#

Hi I have an emun which is going to run test through and if statement.

```
public enum Test_Criteria
    {
        Pass,
        Warning,
        Fail
    }
```

After it has run the if statement

```
if (driver.Url.Contains("Postcode.aspx?type=billing&mode=guest"))
        {

            return Test_Criteria.Pass;
        }

        else
        {
            return Test_Criteria.Fail;  
        }
```

I am getting unreachable code to carry on to the next test straight below here

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Pagecontent_TextBoxPostCode")).SendKeys("#####");
```

What would be the most sensible way to allow the program to continue the code after the return. Thanks

Comment: You need to show more of your code to grasp what you are doing... Post the full code above

Answer (score 3):

You are returning in both `if` and `else` clause, that is why your code would not reach the next line after `if` statement. In case of any condition, if the check fails or not, your code will return from the method. That is why you are getting the error/warning.

Comment: @Saurabh, your answer is fine, just remove the last part, you should undelete your answer, because it provides a way to OP to overcome the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are returning from both branches of the condition. If you want to execute further code, you should not return in either one.

In order to test multiple conditions, you could try something like this: (I assume here that a failing condition stops the test right away)

```
var result = Test_Criteria.Pass;
if ( */fail condition*/ )
{
    return Test_Criteria.Fail;  
}

if ( */another fail condition*/ )
{
    return Test_Criteria.Fail;  
}

if( */warning condition*/ )
{
    result = Test_Criteria.Warning;
}
else if( */another warning condition*/ )
{
    result = Test_Criteria.Warning;
}

return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two execution paths, each returning from your function, so it's indeed impossible to continue after your if-else block.

Try this:

```
var urlContains = driver.Url.Contains("Postcode.aspx?type=billing&mode=guest"));
var result = urlContains ? Test_Critera.Pass : Test_Criteria.Fail;

driver.FindElement(By.Id("Pagecontent_TextBoxPostCode")).SendKeys("#####");
//the rest of your code

return result;
```